# Compilation error : Missing $ inserted in bbl file

Tags: pdftex

I have the following latex sample:

```
    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

    @InProceedings{ttest,
    author="H{\"u}bner, Jomi Fred
    and Sichman, Jaime Sim{\~a}o
    and Boissier, Olivier",
    editor="Boissier, Olivier
    and Padget, Julian
    and Dignum, Virginia
    and Lindemann, Gabriela
    and Matson, Eric
    and Ossowski, Sascha
    and Sichman, Jaime Sim{\~a}o
    and V{\'a}zquez-Salceda, Javier",
    title="{\$}{\backslash}mathcal{\{}S-M{\}}oise^{\{}+{\}}{\$}: A Middleware for Developing Organised Multi-agent Systems",
    booktitle="Coordination, Organizations, Institutions, and Norms in Multi-Agent Systems",
    year="2006",
    publisher="Springer Berlin Heidelberg",
    address="Berlin, Heidelberg",
    pages="64--77",
    isbn="978-3-540-35176-4"
}

\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
something about \cite{ttest} and also.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

When I compile with pdflatex, i get this error:  Missing $ inserted.
the error is located in bbl file

thx in advance.

Comment: What is up with that bibtex entry title. why is `$` escaped? It looks more like it should be `title = "{$\mathcal{S-M}oise^{+}$}: A ...."

Comment: I took the bib entry from the journal website. @daleif: I tried your suggestion but the error still persists.

Comment: did you also delete the `.bbl` file? and then rerun as latex, bibtex, latex, latex?

Comment: @daleif:  yes I cleaned the directory from auxiliary files.

Comment: I have no issues if I use `title="{$\mathcal{S-M}oise^{+}$}: A Middleware for Developing Organised Multi-agent Systems",`, remember that you'll need to delete the generated `.bib` file, if you use the MWE you provided. It is only written once.

Comment: thx @daleif, this has resolved the issue. I forget to delete the bib file.

Comment: I'll write an answer. You might want to look into the `filecontents` package which extends this env with a version that is always overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The journal website you got this from has an over aggressive escape feature. The `title` entry should be

```
title="{$\mathcal{S-M}oise^{+}$}: A Middleware foar Developing Organised Multi-agent Systems",
```

I'd use the `filecontents` package, since the standard `filecontents` env will never overwrite the generated file once it is first created. Confusing users who does not know this.

Here is a corrected MWE with the `filecontents` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

    @InProceedings{ttest,
    author="H{\"u}bner, Jomi Fred
    and Sichman, Jaime Sim{\~a}o
    and Boissier, Olivier",
    editor="Boissier, Olivier
    and Padget, Julian
    and Dignum, Virginia
    and Lindemann, Gabriela
    and Matson, Eric
    and Ossowski, Sascha
    and Sichman, Jaime Sim{\~a}o
    and V{\'a}zquez-Salceda, Javier",
    title="{$\mathcal{S-M}oise^{+}$}: A Middleware foar Developing Organised Multi-agent Systems",
    booktitle="Coordination, Organizations, Institutions, and Norms in Multi-Agent Systems",
    year="2006",
    publisher="Springer Berlin Heidelberg",
    address="Berlin, Heidelberg",
    pages="64--77",
    isbn="978-3-540-35176-4" 
}
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
something about \cite{ttest} and also.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

See the `filecontents` manual for the difference between `filecontents` and `filecontents*`